# How do you print local variables and ?thesis in an Isabelle proof (debugging in Isabelle)?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I sometimes find it hard to use Isabelle because I cannot have a "print command" like in normal programming.

For example, I want to see what `?thesis`. The concrete semantics book says:

> The unknown ?thesis is implicitly matched against any goal stated by lemma or show. Here is a typical example:

My silly sample FOL proof is:

```
lemma
  assumes "(∃ x. ∀ y. x ≤ y)"
  shows "(∀x. ∃ y. y ≤ x)"
proof (rule allI)
  show ?thesis
```

but I get the error:

```
proof (state)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀x. ∃y. y ≤ x 
Failed to refine any pending goal 
Local statement fails to refine any pending goal
Failed attempt to solve goal by exported rule:
  ∀x. ∃y. y ≤ x
```

but I do know why.

I expected

```
?thesis === ⋀x. ∃y. y ≤ x
```

since my proof state is:

```
proof (state)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀x. ∃y. y ≤ x
```

Why can't I print `?thesis`?

It's really annoying to have to write the statement I'm trying to proof if it's obvious. Perhaps it's meant to be explicit but in the examples in chapter 5 they get away with using `?thesis` in:

```
lemma fixes a b :: int assumes "b dvd (a+b)" shows "b dvd a" proof −
have "∃k′. a = b∗k′" if asm: "a+b = b∗k" for k proof
show "a = b∗(k − 1)" using asm by(simp add: algebra_simps) qed
then show ?thesis using assms by(auto simp add: dvd_def ) qed
```

but whenever I try to use `?thesis` I always fail.

Why is it?

Note that this does work:

```
lemma
  assumes "(∃ x. ∀ y. x ≤ y)"
  shows "(∀x. ∃ y. y ≤ x)"
proof (rule allI)
  show "⋀x. ∃y. y ≤ x" proof -
```

but I thought `?thesis` was there to avoid this.

---

Also, `thm ?thesis` didn't work either.

---

Another example is when I use:

```
let ?ys = take k1 xs
```

but I can't print `?ys` value.

---

TODO:

why doesn't:

```
lemma "length(tl xs) = length xs - 1"
  thm (cases xs)
```

show anything? (same if your replaces cases with induction).

Comment: similar question (I asked) worth giving a pointer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777833/what-is-the-best-way-to-search-through-general-definitions-theorems-functions

Answer (score 4):

You can find `?theorem` and others in the print context window:

[image: print context window]

As for why `?thesis` doesn't work, by applying the introduction rule `proof (rule allI)` you are changing the goal, so it no longer matches `?thesis`. The example in the book uses `proof-` which prevents Isabelle from applying any introduction rule.

Comment: In addition, you can use the command `term` to display any term, e.g. `term ?thesis` or `term ?ys`.

Comment: in a related note. I want to see what the output of induction would be. How can I see it? I'd expect something like (for natural numbers): `[| P 0; \forall k. P k --> P (k+1) |] ==> \forall n. P n` as output. Is there something like that to see what induction, cases etc. rules are before apply them? (just like I do `thm HOL.mp`)?

Comment: sorry for the spam. What about functions? For example I have a theorem I am working through in chapter 5.4.1 and I wanted to see the definition of `tl` on lists for example. Using query has not yielded anything yet.

Comment: I noticed that `thm definition_def` does work for definitions but not for functions.

Comment: funny, `thm tl.simps` did NOT work...`f.simps` seems to only work for functions I defined manually...

Answer (score 2):

It seems I asked a very similar question worth pointing to: [What is the best way to search through general definitions, theorems, functions, etc for Isabelle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777833/what-is-the-best-way-to-search-through-general-definitions-theorems-functions)

But here is a list of thing's I've learned so far:

- `thm`: seems to work for definition, lemmas and functions. For definition do `name_def` for a definition with name `name`. For functions do `thm f.simps` for all definitions in the function. For a single one do `thm f.simps(1)` for the first one. For lemmas do `thm lemma_name` or `thm impI` or `HOL.mp` etc.
- `term`: for terms do `term term_name` e.g. in isar `term ?thesis` or `term this`
- `print_theorems`: if you place this after a definition or a function it shows all the theorems defined for those! It's amazing.
- `print...` I just noticed in jedit if you let the auto complete show you the rest for print it has a bunch of options! Probably useful!
- Search engine for Isabelle: https://search.isabelle.in.tum.de/
- You can use Query (TODO: improve this)
- TODO: how to find good way to display stuff about tactics.

I plan to update this as I learn all the ways to debug in Isabelle.